# Problems with default Razor View when deploying to "real" IIs Web Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this ASP.NET MVC 3 application that works fine when developing locally using IIs Express 7.5 or Cassini.
But when i deploy the app to a real web site on IIs 7.5 (even on my local dev box) I get the dreaded

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports
>   the searched locations.
>   The following
>   locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

I have tried the following: 
In `global.asax.cs`, added these lines in the `Application_Start()` method to force it to use the Razor view engine only:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

But to no avail.
I find this error message somewhat difficult to troubleshoot. Can someone give me some pointers on what to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my bad.

A classic example of shooting first then ask. (Or the other way around...)

The Home/`Index.cshtml` file had its Build Actions set to `None` for some reason. Setting it to `Content` solved the problem.